# upgrade sql server 2008r2 to 2016 performance issues

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, sql-server-performance

Does anyone have experience upgrading from SQL Server 2008R2 to 2016?

Our system was running fine on 2008R2 but after upgrading to 2016 we are experiencing high tempdb contention.

We see a large amount of blocking on PAGELATCH_SH waits for tempdb objects. PLE is 99.98%. MAXDOP is 6 (machine has 8 cores/NUMA). MAXDOP threshold is 50.

Random queries are taking upwards of 30 seconds to run but when I try running the same queries from SSMS they run sub-second, which verifies blocking as the issue. We are currently using 16 temp file and increasing to 34 tonight.

We discover today that tempdb log has an io_stall_write_ms over 200,000 ms, we are moving it to a SAN tonight, but I do not believe it explains the long waits for page latches.

I’ve reached the end of my ideas. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Was this an in-place upgrade on the same hardware or did you do a _migration_ upgrade to different hardware?

Comment: `We see a large amount of blocking on PAGELATCH_SH waits for tempdb objects` this statement is not true and this doesn't indicate tempdb contention

Comment: are you following tempdb best practices like log and data files on seperate drives,equally sized data files.Also as per my understanding,you have added more than necessary tempdb data files for your 8 cores

Comment: We moved to new hardware at the same time. We have been reviewing the hardware configuration and are moving to bare metal tonight.

Comment: Yes all tempdb files are the same size. Agree we are beyond the recommended 8. We started with 8 and have been increasing by 4 files, jumping by 8 tonight.

Comment: Thanks Gameiswar, I'm intrigued. If it isn't an indication of tempdb contention what is it? I've read a number of articles  recommending increasing the number of tempdb files when you see page latch waits on tempdb.

Comment: and the tempdb files are on a separate drive. We moved the tempdb log file to it's own drives with no improvement

Comment: did you regression test your database before moving it to SQL Server 2016? What's the current compatibility level of the database? and how did you migrate the database? this seems like a cardinality estimator issue.

Comment: Yes we regression tested the database. We have been running SQL2014 and 2016 in our Dev and QA environments for over 6 months. However, we did not have the means to run a large stress test. Compatibility level is 2016 on all the databases. We cleared up most the problem by recompiling all the stored procedures. We are still seeing occasional spikes in the waits so our next change is try the legacy cardinality estimator.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and it turned out to be the new cardinal estimator. Try changing the compatibility mode for the DB back to 2008 and compare.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't comment on an older post but I came across this when looking into a similar issue we're experiencing. This link is worth looking into as part of an upgrade strategy. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/change-the-database-compatibility-mode-and-use-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017